# Midnight Commander Editor (mcdedit) - Is there a way turning off Fullscreen at startup?

Tags: mc

Midnight Commander has a very good text editor called mcedit. It's got a GUI style Menu bar which is hidden by default (mc refers to this as Fullscreen). If you go and click the star in the top right corner, the menubar is no longer hidden and remains that way (mcedit is no longer in Fullscreen).

Personally, I like having the menu bar out in the open all the time, is there away of permanently disabling the Fullscreen at startup feature?

I've tried both "Options > Save mode" and "Options > Save setup" but that doesn't seem to work.